# Interact-able Table from AD in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, wamp

I am working on a PHP project which requires me to pull data from the AD using SQL and the user needs a way to see everyone. On the page load, the table fills up with users who are in the user's AD group, but if they want to look for someone else, they have the option to search for someone outside of their group and select them via the search bar on top.

My question is, what would be the best way to go about this? Do I completely unload the table and reload it every time someone types into the search bar? Do I reload the page with a different SQL script after they hit 'enter'?

I am using html, JS/JQuery, and PHP on a local WAMP server. I understand that PHP is server side and Javascript/html is more client, so I am having trouble on communicating between both of them.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can use AJAX to change only the table, don't reload all the page. The AJAX will be contain in a function and use jquery to catch the change event of the search box if you want live search

```
 $("#searchBox").change(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", success: function(result){
      $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
  });
```

or only when you click search button

```
$( "#searchButton" ).click(function() {
    $.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", success: function(result){
      $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
  });
```